# Website blocking out curl even with real browser's headers

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I noticed that http://www.momondo.com.cn/ is using some magic technology:
`curl` doesn't work on it. The URL displays fine in a web browser, but `curl` always returns a timeout, even when I add all of the headers like a web browser would.

I also tried Python requests and `urllib2`, but they didn't work either.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>curl -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1" -H "Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8" -H "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
http://www.momondo.com.cn/
* About to connect() to www.momondo.com.cn port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 184.50.91.106...
* connected
* Connected to www.momondo.com.cn (184.50.91.106) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.momondo.com.cn
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
> Cache-Control:no-cache
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
> Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
```

Why and how does this happen? How does Momondo escape `curl`?

Comment: This is too broad. There are many techniques to fingerprint non-browser traffic; the best way to crawl things is using a headless browser.

Comment: Yes, i know this, some websites can detect by Javascript. But i am surprised momondo can detect by the first quest which just the same as a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting up the request?  If you are using `requests` you should use the [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object type and change the headers there so they can be easily reused.  It doesn't look like they are doing anything special because using telnet directly on that site (i.e. `telnet www.momondo.com.cn 80`) with the headers generated by the browser (captured via `tcpdump`, just to be sure) resulted in content returned rather than hanging till timeout.  Also, it pays attention to look at what CDN (content delivery network) the site is behind, and in this case the address resolves to some subdomain at `akamaiedge.net` which means it might be useful to check out [why they might have blocked you](https://community.akamai.com/community/cloud-security/blog/2016/04/07/why-is-akamai-blocking-me).

Anyway, using the headers you have supplied with a `requests.Session` object, a response was generated.

```
>>> from requests import Session
>>> session = Session()
>>> session.headers  # check the default headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.12.5', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*'}
>>> session.headers['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
>>> session.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4'
>>> session.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0'
>>> session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36'
>>> response = session.get('http://www.momondo.com.cn/')
>>> response
<Response [200]>
```

Doesn't seem to be anything magic at all.

Comment: Thanks. requests's session use keep-alive and use encoding default. So it works.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the reason:

momondo is using following methods to block unreal web clients.

1. Detect the user-agent. Can not be curl's default UA.
2. Detect the "Connection" header. Must use "keep-alive" rather than "Keep-Alive" in my initial test.
3. Detect the "Accept-Encoding" header. Can not be empty, can use anything.

Finally i can use curl to get the content now:

> curl -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
>   10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89
>   Safari/537.36" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept-Encoding:
>   nothing" http://www.momondo.com.cn/

BTW, I have doing webscraping for about seven years. This is the first time i met a website used this anti-scraping method. Mark it.

Comment: Just so you know, the `Accept-Encoding` header can be replaced with `Accept-Language` header, too, e.g. `-H "Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8"`.  Pretty sure it checks against a number of headers and if the minimum number checks out the requests go through.

Comment: You are right. And i notice it may track the ip with the browser version. e.g. 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0' works, while '... Firefox/17.0' desn't work.

Comment: Also it may remember your browser. If you use "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" first, then use "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) " will not work.